# Callback Based SimpleActionClient with Python

Tags: ros, simpleactionclient, callback, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tutorial shows how to do it with C++ : http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Callback%20Based%20Simple%20Action%20Client

Does anyone know how to do it in Python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172919/callback-based-simpleactionclient-with-python/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Actionlib Tutorials Page](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials) includes an [Actionlib Client Python Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Client%20%28Python%29)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-06-06**:
The goal of using callback based action clients is to avoid using waitForResult and having different callbacks for result and feedback, which is not the case in the link you sent me. The purpose of this is to use only the feedback from the action and not the result. (Continuous face recognition in face_recognition package for example)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-06**:
If you're not calling an action for the result, you might want to rethink your use of actionlib. You can also look at the Actionlib API documentation: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/actionlib/html/index.html .

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-06-09**:
Ok thanks. Would you suggest something for that use case? activating/disabling face recognition for example

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-09**:
activating and deactivating image processing pipelines is tricky. They usually have some temporal state, and a pretty significant startup time. I've seen solutions that only run the pipeline when there is a subscriber. You could also try using capabilities to start and stop the node.